# baseUrl is not working in my MEAN stack app, How to fix this?

Tags: node.js, express

I have created ope application using MEAN stack. Everything is working properly in previous but when i enter to set baseUrl it's not working properly.

### config.js

```
 module.exports = {

"database": "mongodb://localhost:27017/fuse",
"port": process.env.PORT || 7200,
"secretKey": "YourSecretKey",


baseUrl: 'http://192.168.2.8:3000',
setBaseUrl : function(url){
    this.baseUrl = url;
},
getBaseUrl : function(){
    return this.baseUrl;
}
```

}

### app.js

```
var express    =    require('express');
var config = require('./config');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var url = require('url');
var http = require('http');


http.createServer(function (req, res) {
var hostname = req.headers.host; // hostname = 'localhost:7200'
console.log(hostname);
config.setBaseUrl(hostname);
var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname; // pathname = '/MyApp'
console.log('http://' + config.getBaseUrl() + pathname);

res.writeHead(200);
res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are using express, why don't you create your server with it?

```
var app = express();

var port = 3000;

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.getUrl = function() {
        return req.protocol + "://" + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;
    }
    return next();
});

app.listen(port, function {
    console.log('Server running on port ' + port);

});
```

This way you'll always have your url in req.getUrl.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have 'FUSE' theme, in that gulp is running on port 3000. If i create a node using same port it shows error.

Comment: can't you use another port for express? Like 3001?

Comment: ha yes, i used one more port number, now it is working. Thank you.